# How to trim text after special character \n in js

Tags: javascript

In the following text:

```
text\n\nWhy';
```

I'm trying to get rid of everything after \ (sign included) so that my output will be:
text

how can I do it?
Tried:

```
var s = 'text\n\nWhy';
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('\'));
console.log (s)
```

Comment: The substring method works perfectly fine, but I wanted to let you know about another way to get parts of a string based on the index of something:

`var s = 'text\n\nWhy';`
`var sub = s.split('\n')[0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\n` is an [escape character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Using_special_characters_in_strings) for newline. You will need to search for that "character".

```js
var s = 'text\n\nWhy';
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('\n'));
console.log (s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string in array and just keep the first element :

```
var fullText = 'text\n\nWhy';
var result = fullText.split('\n')[0];
console.log (result);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `\n` instead of `\` as it's escaped.